# Is there a Java API for touching devices such as tablets?

Tags: java, windows, touchscreen

I'm a java developer and I love this techonology. However, in my advisor next research we are going to use extensively touch-screen devices on **Windows**. This is a problem for me, because I'm used to programming on Linux and with Java.

**The question is, is there an API for Java for touchscreen devices?** If yes, is this API good/mature? The need for a Java API is not only because I love Java but because I don't know how to program specifically to Windows, that is, I've never used Win32 or .NET. If there isn't is there something available for Mono? I hate to exclude platforms.

Comment: If you hate to exclude platforms, I would recommend using the API that is native for that platform.  Win32 and .NET are different, but why limit yourself to a single language? In ten years (for example) you're really going to wish you knew another development system besides java.

Comment: @KevinDTimm it's be cause I'm used to Java. I'm thinking on learning C# to do this, as it seems the API is really easy. I think I'll follow your and my professor advise, the right tool for the right job. It seems that Java is not the right tool, and I should probably learn new tools/languages. :)

Comment: Touchscreen events are converted to regular mouse events, unless you need more sophisticated touch events (e.g. pressure, touch size, etc) you should only need to use regular awt's MouseListener

Comment: @Lie: Or multitouch, or gestures, or just knowing you're on a tablet and won't be receiving mouse-move events with no buttons pressed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gosh, if you really want to offer a bounty on a question that can be answered in 6 seconds using google:

- https://sites.google.com/site/gmitresearch/mt4j/mt4j-basics
- http://code.google.com/p/sparsh-ui/
- http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2008/pdf/TS-6127.pdf
- [How to develop multi-touch applications in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369301/how-to-develop-multi-touch-applications-in-java)

Comment: It because the question was ignored, and I didn't find it on google.

Comment: unfortunately mt4j is no longer a live project.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but i find it may still be useful.
Java Swing does not have native support for touch-events. However, Java FX does. Java FX is already integrated in Java SE 7 and 8 and could be installed on Java SE 6.
[See this article from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/gestures.htm#CHDDHFJJ)