# A Java Swing application Can be executed in POS Ready Operating System with touch screen machine?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, wamp

I am responsible to develop POS using java swing framework and mysql server in wamp server and POS machine is touch system. All the event should be trigger on touch event. I need to know following stuff are possible in this scenario.

1. Can run java application (my pos) on POS Ready Operating System ?
2. Can use mysql server in wamp on POS Ready Operating System?
3. Is it possible to use button, drop down to select menu items, text field in touch event to trigger functions related to above components. 
   4.And what are the event I should used for example ,mouse clicked, action performed ?

I need immediate answer for above questions and factors to be consider from expert of POS Ready OS , Java Swing

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need WAMP?  You do not need Apache or PHP if you're writing a Swing app (unless you're going to use REST services for storage...).

> > Can run java application (my pos) on POS Ready OS ?

Yes, if it supports Java.  You didn't say what OS.

> > Can use mysql server in wamp on POS Ready OS?

Yes, if it's Windows (WAMP is **Windows**, Apache, Mysql, and PHP)

> > Is it possible to use button, drop down to select menu items, text field in touch event to trigger functions related to above components.

Yes

Also, see here:

[Programming a touch screen application with SWING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707101/programming-a-touch-screen-application-with-swing?rq=1)