# Java Swing - Touch Screen - L & F

Tags: java, touch, look-and-feel

I am developing a touch screen based application in Java (using Swing) for a Automat Machine something like [this](http://www.zeix.com/aktuelles-publikationen/wp-content/uploads-zeix.com/2009/07/zvv-ticket.jpg). As the operating system takes care of all the touch events, I just have to develop a desktop application and use it on the touch device.

I would appreciate if some can help me
i) to remove the mouse pointer from the touch screen
ii) and also to get a Look and Feel similar to the one should above (I use Ubuntu as Operating System and the look and feel is not so attractive)

[Some Hint - But not complete](http://java.sun.com/products/personaljava/touchable/#The%20Touchable)

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456961/is-there-a-java-api-for-touching-devices-such-as-tablets

Answer (score 1):

Iam developing a similar touch based fullscreen swing app and to hide the mouse cursor iam setting a transparent mouse pointer on my main frame window as follows:

```
int[] pixels = new int[16 * 16];
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
        new MemoryImageSource(16, 16, pixels, 0, 16));
Cursor transparentCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
        .createCustomCursor(image, new Point(0, 0),
                "invisibleCursor");
mainAppFrame.setCursor(transparentCursor);
```

As for the look and feel iam actually using a custom extension of metal l&f where i have rewritten the ButtonUI paint method to get a JButton that look much like what you want. I would recommend you to try to do the same, is quite fun and not that difficult.