# Adding multitouch support to an AWT application

Tags: java, awt, multi-touch

I have an existing AWT Java desktop application. Is there a library or something I can use to have it respond to multitouch gestures (in Windows 7/8)? I see there's frameworks like MT4J or JavaFX that have multitouch support, but it seems these are separate UI frameworks that I can't use with my existing app?

Comment: I know nothing of this topic but I did find this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456961/is-there-a-java-api-for-touching-devices-such-as-tablets