# adding gestures without gesture builder

Tags: java, android, gesture

I'm working on a Gesture based application launcher.I need to add custom gestures from the application to the gesture library. I tried the method with Gesture builder and copying it to res/raw, It worked. But i need to add more Gestures through my applications add gesture menu..help

Comment: could be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369301/how-to-develop-multi-touch-applications-in-java

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want, but if you need keep and modify `GestureLibrary` you can read and write it at filesystem like this:

```
final String fileName = "gestures";
final String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
final File storeFile = new File(dir, fileName);
final GestureLibrary gesturelib = GestureLibraries.fromFile(storeFile);
```

Code of creating gestures you can get from `GestureBuilder` [example](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/gesturesample/src/com/varma/samples/gesturesample) (Sorry, I found only this source, but it copy well-known example with changed names of variables) and read about in [how-to](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html).

Or about what gestures you asked?

Comment: When I draw a circle by hand with the gesture builder, it is far from the perfect shape. I want a way to clean the path, so that the GestureLibrary works with smaller and better references. I expected that the shape to be described with a Bézier curve in an XML file, but it is binary.

Comment: @rds You need to read/parse `Gestures` with a readable format? `Gesture` keep 'GestureStroke' (I think it can be discribed only with strokes) inside that using for creating `Bitmap`. You can look at in source (`toBitmap()`-method):
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/gesture/Gesture.java

You can construct `Gesture` with `GestureStroke`s use `addStroke()`-method. You need special parser-converter to create `Gesture` from special data. I don't know any, but you easy can create one (xml2gesture) :).

Comment: It can be usefull. How GestureLibrary work with gesture-files:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/gesture/GestureStore.java#GestureStore.readFormatV1%28java.io.DataInputStream%29
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/gesture/GestureStore.java#GestureStore.save%28java.io.OutputStream%2Cboolean%29

At top of the source placed structure of file.

Comment: The answer per se is not what I was expecting, but the pointers to the source code are useful.