# Will a native GUI based desktop application respond to touch events on a tablet?

Tags: java, tablet

I have never worked on android before and hence I am presuming that implementing touch/mouse events for a tablet/mobile application might slightly be different compared to events triggered in GUI components of native programming languages.

This question is not related to Android though. If I completely remove all traces of Android OS from a tablet, load and mount it with just a Linux kernel with jvm/jre installed, and few jars that launch a custom java GUI application i.e in such a way that the tablet boots and starts with the custom java application by default, Will this native swing based desktop application respond to mouse events triggered by touch? If yes, is it as good as that in Android?

PS: Precisely, With more emphasis on mouse click, mouse entered and mouse exited events..

Comment: Quite a hardware/platform-specific support issue here: Have you checked [Multitouch for Java (MT4J)](http://www.mt4j.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page)?

Comment: SO link on the issue: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369301/how-to-develop-multi-touch-applications-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369301/how-to-develop-multi-touch-applications-in-java)