# How to use the Touchscreen in Java as "Mouse"/ Touch Input

Tags: java, multi-touch, touchscreen

In Paint (in Windows) i can use all of my fingers to paint. However in Java i was not able to use more than one finger( Mouse Pointer) at the same time.

In my application I create a piano and it would be cool to be able to play 2 or more Notes at same time. I use a MouseListener an ActionListener.

So far I spend a lot of hours for this problem and could not get the following to work:

- MT4J
- JWinPointer
- JavaFX
- (SMT)

MT4J:
I could only use one Pointer (my mouse) an nothing else.

JWinPointer:
I could not import the module. However I think it want to use a stylus an I use my fingers.

JavaFX:
With the JFXPanel there was always a NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel

SMT:
I don't know whether this helps me.

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369301/how-to-develop-multi-touch-applications-in-java this might help you out

Comment: Gesture Works must be licenced and Simple Multi Touch is for Processing :/

Answer (score 0):

My solution: Delete Eclipse and download NetBeans - Here does JavaFX work